# Scaffolding with node.js, express and mongoose like grails?

Tags: node.js, grails, express, mongoose, scaffolding

Is there a way to generate routes/controllers and views for node.js/express from mongoose models?

Like the grails generate-all command creates all controllers and views files for full CRUD functionality on existing models?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any native way to do that, but you can use the [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) project to generate some scaffolding based on the templates they have available. They have a [node/express](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express) generator.

Answer (score 0):

Even if my answer is late, the short answer is **no**.

Express cannot generate full CRUD functionality for all your mongoose models automatically. In part that is because express is sufficiently un-opinionated to not even assume you use mongoose in its basic package (or any database functionality for that matter).

Its unopinionatedness is part of the reason why express is so flexible -- but it also means more work upfront (consider this: If you used sequelize (to connect to, say, PostgreSQL or MySQL) to define models: would you then ask the express project to include CRUD generators for that too?). It doesn't even come with administrative auth packages (even though such solutions do exist, like [lockit](https://github.com/zeMirco/lockit)); this is all pluggable extensions (unfortunately this means a lot of package swamp to navigate, but let's not degrade this answer into a blog post).

There is the [formage project](https://github.com/Empeeric/formage) which attempts to build forms from models for admin GUIs. You might want to check on that. There possibly are other similar projects too.

*Now I realize that that was of course not what the question was aiming for, but I will record a possible way to do it here:*

If you wish to implement these things, you might go the following route:

- Use sessions.
- Implement your models using [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) or [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com).
- Implement authentication using [lockit](https://github.com/zeMirco/lockit) or [passport](http://passportjs.org/) (or any other authn framework).
- Implement authorization using [node-acl](https://github.com/optimalbits/node_acl) (or any other authz framework of your choosing)
- Implement the desired CRUD functionality using e. g. [formage project](https://github.com/Empeeric/formage).

(better ideas welcome in the comments; will update the answer in that case.)